# Glitch while scrolling the page

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3, scroll

I see a clutter/glitch while scrolling down my page. I have tried removing some js and css files. Also tried adding smoothscroll property but nothing worked. Can anyone check the issue and provide some solution for this?
Thanks

Comment: I tried js code for scrollspeed to 900 but it did not work either.

Comment: At the end of the head tag you have some script that overrides mouse scroll. Try removing that. I am guessing it is connected to some parallax effect plugin.